# htaccess redirect except homepage and language versions of the site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress site www.myoldsite.com

The homepage of the site has nothing but 4 links.

```
English - links to my new site www.mynewsite.com
French - links to www.myoldsite.com/fr
German - links to www.myoldsite.com/de
Russian - links to www.myoldsite.com/ru
```

I want all old site pages to be redirected to the new site's home page except the homepage and language versions of the site.

```
www.myoldsite.com should not be redirected 
www.myoldsite.com/fr should not be redirected 
www.myoldsite.com/de should not be redirected 
www.myoldsite.com/de should not be redirected
```

but anything else after forward slash should be redirected to the new site's home page. i.e.

```
www.myoldsite.com/page1
www.myoldsite.com/page2
```

etc. should all be redirected to www.mynewsite.com.

Can anyone please help?

Below is my htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you consider to use a plugin? This could be a solution: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site for generates redirects

http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

or google it **.htaccess Redirect Code Generator**